# How to attach the datepicker to each row of a table having a same ID?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker

I have a JavaScript function to attach the date picker to each row data of the table and row is dynamically created and uses this date picker function to attached to the field.But the problem is if I created additional row to the table its is  attaching the date picker but in that additional row that datepicker is not working its look like disable state.

```js
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input.add").live('click', function() {
     var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
     var $clone = $tr.clone();
     $clone.find(':text').val('');
     $clone.find(':checkbox:checked').prop('checked', false).val('N');
     $tr.after($clone);
  });
  $("input.delete").live('click', function() {
     var rowCount = document.getElementById('phone').getElementsByTagName("tr").length;
     if (rowCount != 3) {
        var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        $tr.remove();
        return false;
     }
  });
});

$(function() {
  $("#dob").datepicker({
     //showOn: both - datepicker will appear clicking the input box as well as the calendar icon
     //showOn: button - datepicker will appear only on clicking the calendar icon
     showOn: 'button',
     //you can use your local path also eg. buttonImage: 'images/x_office_calendar.png'
     buttonImage: 'file:///C:/Users/27983/Desktop/calender.jpg',
     buttonImageOnly: true,
     changeMonth: true,
     changeYear: true,
     duration: 'fast',
     dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
  });
});
</script>
```

```css
 <style>
   #ui-datepicker-div {
  font-size: 12px;
   }
   
   #datepicker {}
</style>
```

```html
  <body>
   <form name="Basicinfo" id="Basicinfo" method="post" action="Basic.html">
  <!-- Start Header -->
  <table id="phone" width="100%" name="phone">
     <tr>
        <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#5C85B3">Phone</td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <th>Type</td>
           <th>Date</th>
           <th>*Phone</th>
           <th>Preferred</th>
           <th>Add/Delete</th>
     </tr>
     <tr>
        <td>
           <select name="phntype" id="phntype" style="width:50%"></select>
        </td>
        <td>
           <input id="dob" name="dob" type="text" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
           <input type="text" name="phone_no" id="phone_no" value="">
        </td>
        <td>
           <input type="hidden" name="prefferd" value="NO">
           <input type="checkbox" name="preferred" id="preferred" value="N" onchange="changeCheckBox();">
        </td>
        <td>
           <input type="button" value="+" class="add">
           <input type="button" value="-" class="delete">
        </td>
     </tr>
  </table>
 </form>
</body>
```

Comment: IDs must be unique. You can use a common class

Comment: @Satpal Iknow ID should be unique but requirement is like id should not change for all the row and the based on date it will populate the row data.

Comment: Then you can use attribute value selector `$("[id=dob]").datepicker({`, but for newly added row to have to set in manually it won't be set automatically. And you are using `clone` so try once with `$tr.clone(true)`

Comment: @Satpal  i have tried like $("[id=dob]").datepicker({ this but still its not working .

Answer (score 3):

You know, the id attribute should be unique. You are better off setting a class:

```
<input class="datePickerInput" name="dob" type="text" value="">
```

and then selecting it by class rather than by id:

```
$(".datePickerInput").datepicker({
```

Comment: I am trying by using class but its not working can u check on this

Comment: Works fine in this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/03jx77zp/ Maybe put the .datepicker(); in the $(document).ready(function() {

Comment: is there any way to select that particular row datepicker id to call datepicker function.

Comment: The class selector selects them all for you. However you can always create unique id for each input and then select them by id with a for cycle.

Comment: you can hold a js counter variable to hold the current number of rows, and append that number to each newly created date field's id in the new row as id attribute

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
 <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

 $(function() {
   $('input').filter('.datepicker').datepicker({
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    showOn: 'button',
    buttonImage: 'jquery/images/calendar.gif',
    buttonImageOnly: true
   });
  });      

  <p>Date1 <input  class="datepicker" type="text" readonly="true"></p>
 <p>Date2<input class="datepicker" type="text" readonly="true"></p>
 <p>Date3<input  class="datepicker" type="text" readonly="true"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
                var count = 0;
                $(".add").on("click",function(){
                    count = count+1;
                    var curid = 'date'+count;
                    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
                    var $clone = $tr.clone();
                    $clone.find(':text').val('');
                    $clone.find('.date').attr('id',curid).attr('class','date').datepicker();
                    $clone.find(':checkbox:checked').prop('checked', false).val('N');
                    $tr.after($clone);
                });
                $(".date").datepicker();
            });

<table  id="phone" width="100%" name="phone">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#5C85B3">Phone</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th>Type</td>
                <th>Date</th>
                <th>*Phone</th>
                <th>Preferred</th>
                <th>Add/Delete</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name="phntype" id="phntype" style="width:50%"></select>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input class="date" id="dob" name="dob" type="text" value="" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="phone_no" id="phone_no" value="" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="hidden" name="prefferd" value="NO" />
                    <input type="checkbox" name="preferred" id="preferred" value="N" onchange ="changeCheckBox();" />
                </td>
                <td>
                    <input type="button" value="+" class="add" />
                    <input type="button" value="-" class="delete" />
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Just added a class to the dynamically added date input field and binded the datepicker to it.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/03jx77zp/2/)

Comment: its working But the Problem if is choose the date in the second row it is updating the first row

Comment: try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/03jx77zp/2/
you'l have to add the id attribute for uniqueness in each row

Comment: its Working fine but the problem is if i select the date picker for two row after that if i am going to add one more row its not adding any additional row.